# TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not 'str' error while making sign in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, typeerror

When I am trying to add `username` and `password` in the sign in page, it gives me an error:

> TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not 'str'

The issue is occurring in the sign-in page. The whole code is listed below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import StringVar


class panel:
    def ask(self):
        ask = tkinter.Tk()
        ask.title("Input")
        ask.geometry("300x100")

        def y():
            ask.destroy()
            self.login()
        def n():
            ask.destroy()
            self.signup()


        stat = tkinter.Label(ask , text = "Are You An Existing User?")
        stat.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
        yes = tkinter.Button(ask, text = "Yes" , bg = "Blue" , fg = "Black" , command = y, bd = 5 )
        yes.grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
        no = tkinter.Button(ask, text = "No" , bg = "Blue", fg = "Black" , command = n, bd = 5)
        no.grid(row = 1 , column = 2)

        ask.mainloop()

    def signup(self):
        window = tkinter.Tk()
        window.title("Registration Form")
        window.geometry("300x300")

        var = StringVar()

        def callback():
            file = open("information.txt", "a")
            file.write("\r")
            file.write("Data: ")
            file.write(firstname1.get())
            file.write(" ")
            file.write(lastname1.get())
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(firstname1.get())
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(lastname1.get())
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(email1.get())
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(password1.get())
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(var.get())
            file.write("\r")
            file.close()
            messagebox.showinfo("Signup", "You have Successfully Signed Up")
            self.login()

        firstname = tkinter.Label(window, text= "First Name", bg = "Black",fg = "White")
        firstname.grid(row= 0, column= 0)
        firstname1= tkinter.Entry(window,bd= 5)
        firstname1.grid(row= 0 , column = 1)
        lastname = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Last Name", bg = "Black", fg = "White")
        lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        lastname1= tkinter.Entry(window, bd = 5)
        lastname1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        email = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Email", bg = "Black", fg = "White")
        email.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        email1 = tkinter.Entry(window, bd = 5)
        email1.grid(row = 2 , column = 1)

        password = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Password" , bg = "Black", fg = "White")
        password.grid(row = 3 , column = 0)
        password1= tkinter.Entry(window, bd = 5)
        password1.grid(row = 3 , column = 1)

        gender= tkinter.Label(window, text = "Gender", bg = "Black", fg = "White")
        gender.grid(row = 4 , column = 0)
        male = tkinter.Radiobutton(window,text= "Male" , value = "Male", variable = var )
        male.grid(row = 4 , column = 1 , sticky = "nsew")
        female = tkinter.Radiobutton(window,text= "Female" , value= "Female" , variable = var)
        female.grid(row = 4, column = 2 , sticky = "nsew")



        button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Submit" ,command = callback , bg = "Blue", fg = "White" , height = 2, width = 14)
        button.grid(row = 5  , column = 1 , rowspan= 315)



        window.mainloop()

    def login(self):
        signin = tkinter.Tk()
        signin.title("Sign In")
        signin.geometry("300x300")

        def callback():
            file = open("information.txt" , "r")
            e = file.read(x1.get())
            print(e)
            p = file.read(y1.get())
            print(p)
            if e in file and p in file:
                messagebox.showinfo("SignIn Notification", "You are Successfully Signed In")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Email or Password is Incorrect")
            file.close()


        x = tkinter.Label(signin, text = "Email", bg = "Black", fg = "White" )
        x.grid(row =  0 , column = 0)
        x1 = StringVar(tkinter.Entry(signin, bd = 5).grid(row = 0 , column = 1))
        y = tkinter.Label(signin, text = "Password", bg = "Black", fg = "White")
        y.grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
        y1 = StringVar(tkinter.Entry(signin, bd = 5).grid(row = 1 , column = 1))


        login = tkinter.Button(signin, text = "Sign In" , bd = 5, bg = "Blue" , fg = "Black", height = 2 , width = 10, command = callback )
        login.grid(row  = 2 , column = 1, rowspan = 2)

        signin.mainloop()


def main():
    p  = panel()
    p.ask()
main()
```

Comment: show the stack trace of the error

Comment: We mean the full error.

Comment: You are using multiple instances of Tk. You should instead be using `Toplevel` for new windows and one instance of `Tk` for the root.

Comment: What do you think `tk.StringVar(tk.Entry(root, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=1))` is doing? Honestly I have never seen someone try this but it is not doing what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The main reason for your error is that `get()` returns a string and `read()` either takes no arguments or an integer. The integer just tells how many bytes to read.
2. The way you have written your callback even if it worked would actually work if any user and any password matched not just for that specific user. Personally I would store this information in a dictionary and then check each user in that dictionary for the email and password.
3. I would place all the entry values and the StringVar into a list dynamically so we can use it when creating a new user.
4. You are currently using multiple instances of `Tk()` and should only be using one. In order to do the same thing you are doing now we can either use a central frame we can update per window our use `Toplevel()` to create new windows.
5. You can actually build all this functionality into a single class if you want. Right now you have a lot of different things going on that may not need to be. For example your functions `y` and `n` can be deleted.
6. You may want to look into PEP8 standards. Your spacing is all over the place.

After reworking your code I reduced it from 128 lines to 94. I could probably reduce it further but I didn't want to make anything too confusing.

Here is a reworked example of your code let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import json


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Input")
        self.geometry("300x100")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.lbl_list = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Password', 'Gender']
        self.entry_list = []
        self.build_pain_1()

    def clear_frame(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def build_pain_1(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        tk.Label(self.frame, text="Are You An Existing User?").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.frame, text="Yes", bg="Blue", fg="Black", command=self.login, bd=5).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.frame, text="No", bg="Blue", fg="Black", command=self.signup, bd=5).grid(row=1, column=2)

    def signup_callback(self):
        with open("information.txt", "r") as f:
            file_dict = json.load(f)

        new_dict = {}
        for ndex, value in enumerate(self.lbl_list):
            print(self.entry_list[ndex].get())
            new_dict[value] = self.entry_list[ndex].get()
        file_dict["user {}".format(len(file_dict)+1)] = new_dict

        with open("information.txt", "w") as file:
            json.dump(file_dict, file, indent=4)
        self.login()

    def signup(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        self.title("Registration Form")
        self.geometry("300x300")

        for ndex, txt in enumerate(self.lbl_list):
            if ndex+1 < len(self.lbl_list):
                tk.Label(self.frame, text=txt, bg="Black", fg="White").grid(row=ndex, column=0)
                self.entry_list.append(tk.Entry(self.frame, bd=5))
                self.entry_list[-1].grid(row=ndex, column=1)
            if ndex+1 == len(self.lbl_list):
                tk.Label(self.frame, text="Gender", bg="Black", fg="White").grid(row=ndex, column=0)
                self.entry_list.append(tk.StringVar(self))

        tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Male", value="Male", variable=self.entry_list[-1],
                       tristatevalue="x").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Female", value="Female", variable=self.entry_list[-1],
                       tristatevalue="x").grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        tk.Button(self.frame, text="Submit", bg="Blue", fg="White", height=2,
                  command=self.signup_callback).grid(row=5, column=1)

    def login_callback(self):
        e = self.email.get()
        p = self.passw.get()
        valid_login = False
        with open("information.txt", "r") as f:
            file_dict = json.load(f)

        for key, value in file_dict.items():
            if file_dict[key]["Email"] == e and file_dict[key]["Password"] == p:
                messagebox.showinfo("SignIn Notification", "You are Successfully Signed In")
                valid_login = True

        if not valid_login:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Email or Password is Incorrect")

    def login(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        self.title("Sign In")
        self.geometry("300x300")

        tk.Label(self.frame, text="Email", bg="Black", fg="White").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.email = tk.Entry(self.frame, bd=5)
        self.email.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Label(self.frame, text="Password", bg="Black", fg="White").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.passw = tk.Entry(self.frame, bd=5)
        self.passw.grid(row=1, column=1)

        tk.Button(self.frame, text="Sign In", bd=5, bg="Blue", fg="Black", height=2, width=10,
                  command=self.login_callback).grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.read()` takes integers only.
But `x1.get()` always returns a string. If `x1.get()` was a number in string form, you could cast `int(x1.get())`. But I don't think it is.

Let me try to fix some of the code for you:

```
x1 = StringVar(tkinter.Entry(signin, bd = 5).grid(row = 0 , column = 1))
x1.get()
```

always returns an empty string for me. Instead try:

```
x1 = tkinter.Entry(signin, bd = 5)
x1.grid(row=0, column = 1)
x1.get()
```

I can only guess what you're trying to do with `file.read(x1.get())`, but if you want to see if the email and password you put in are in your information.txt, you can do as follows:

```
file = open("information.txt", "r")
information = file.read()
if x1.get() in text and y1.get() in information:
...
```

Comment: In the middle block of code in your question you're calling `x1.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry. It will always be an empty string since the user won't have had a chance to enter anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley I should have been more clear: The x1.get() itself in the callback function while the creation of x1 is in the outer login function. Can you help me clarify this in my post?